# Numba typed lists with homogeneous-signature functions

Tags: python, list, numba

I have some numba-jitted event functions with equal signature, i.e.:

```py
from numba import jit

@jit("Tuple((float64,float64))(float64[::1])", nopython=True)
def event_1(y): 
    return 1.1, 1.2 # (random values for this example)

@jit("Tuple((float64,float64))(float64[::1])", nopython=True)
def event_2(y): 
    return 2.1, 2.2 # (random values for this example)
```

My goal is to create a jitted-function which returns a List of event functions.
The event_handler output is supposed to be the input of another cache-compiled jitted-function and so its signature must be fixed:

```py
from numba.typed import List
@jit("ListType(FunctionType(Tuple((float64, float64))(float64[::1])))()", nopython=True)
def event_handler(): 
    return List([event_1, event_2])
```

However, the code above only works if the List returned by `event_handler` has at least two different event functions. If the List has only 1 event-function item, or multiple items of the same function (e.g., either `List([event_1])` or `List([event_1, event_1])`), the code above cannot compile and produces the following error:

```
No conversion from ListType[type(CPUDispatcher(<function event_1 at 0x7f83c2a22430>))] to ListType[FunctionType[UniTuple(float64 x 2)(array(float64, 1d, C))]]
```

I believe the reason is because in the latter case the List item-type is set equal to the function CPUDispatcher rather than the typed function signature. I've already tried [this](https://numba.discourse.group/t/typed-list-of-jitted-functions-in-jitclass/413/4) solution to initialise the list but unfortunately it does not work.

How can I solve this issue? It seems strange to me that the list type is inferred correctly when two different functions are provided but suddendly inherits a CPUDispatcher type whenever a single item is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which involves explicit typing of the list arguments and the `empty_list` method of `typed list`. With reference to my original post, I can initialize the List with the `empty_list` method, passing as argument its signature (defined outside the scope of any jitted function):

```py
from numba import types
from numba.typed import List

vector_sig = types.Array(dtype=types.float64, ndim=1, layout="C")
function_sig = types.FunctionType(types.Tuple((types.float64, types.float64))(vector_sig))

@jit("ListType(FunctionType(Tuple((float64, float64))(float64[::1])))()", nopython=True)
def event_handler(): 
    event_list = List.empty_list(function_sig)
    event_list.append(event_1)
    return event_list
```